# Development for iPhone on PPC-based computer

Tags: iphone, macos, intel

It has been said elsewhere that developing for iPhone [requires an Intel-based computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190662/whats-the-cheapest-mac-development-box-possible), but this doesn't seem to be the case according to the few introductory Apple docs I've read. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/gettingstarted/docs/iphonedevtools.action) for example, which says merely, "To develop applications for iPhone OS, you need a Mac OS X computer running the Xcode tools." Can anyone provide a reference?

Comment: I started developing iPhone applications on a PowerBook G4.

Comment: NOTA BENE: The answers below were correct when this question was asked in 2009, but they are no longer accurate. [Mac OS X 10.7 and later do not run on PowerPC systems](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/whats-the-last-os-x-that-supported-power-pc), and Mac OS X 10.10 or later is required to run the current version of XCode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have successfully compiled, simulated and device debugged iPhone apps from a PowerPC G5 for every version of the iPhone SDK up to but not including iPhone SDK 3.0.

You only need to edit two things: [change Xcode's installer script](http://secret.hnc.cc/archives/116-How-to-get-the-iPhone-SDK-installing-on-PPC.html) so the installer will install it on a PowerPC and [change the default Simulator configuration](http://blog.flextip.net/en/2008/12/iphone-no-architectures-to-compile-for-ppc/) so it considers PPC a valid simulator target architecture.

It is sometimes flakey installing onto a device from a PPC but it will work.

For iPhone SDK 3.0, Apple have not built the Interface Builder components with PPC code. This means it is impossible (no hack or workaround) to use the SDK 3.0 Interface Builder. The fun of building and running iPhone apps on the PPC will end soon -- likely Snow Leopard where Xcode itself will likely lose PPC code (not that PPC users will be running Snow Leopard anyway but Xcode updates for Snowless Leopard will end).

Summary: Yes, it works on PPC. Yes, debugging the device from a PPC is flakey. No, it won't last long -- the PPC code will slowly be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Cnet [has instructions](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10115416-233.html) on setting it up on PPC. Just remember that Apple's not likely to be much help with it - it's entirely unsupported, as it requires a hack to even work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I believe Apple says it's intel-only, but there are certainly cases of people getting at least part of it working on PPC: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2008/03/iphone-sdk-not-just-intel-only-anymore.ars

There are other hits on Google that tell you how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say a big thank you and recommendation for Alex Blewitt's PPC iPhone SDK installer script. He [packaged](http://alblue.blogspot.com/2008/12/enabling-iphone-development-on-ppc-macs.html) a tool that does the whole thing for you complete with simple instructions. I just got it running on my Powerbook 12" which I travel with.

Answer (score -1):

http://blog.flextip.net/2008/12/iphone-no-architectures-to-compile-for-ppc/

This link is good for me. I was installed SDK on PPC successfull