# Can I download and run XCode & Apple iOS 4.1 on Apple Power PC G5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, intel

I am new and want to start developing apps for iPhone, but I can't afford the high price tag of one of Apple's Intel machine right now, can I start developing iPhone apps on Apple Power PC G5 or Apple MacBook Pro with Intel? Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would someone vote this question down without commenting on why?  On meta there is a nice discussion on being nice to new people. +1 from me.

Comment: this question should be moved.  Programmers perhaps?

Comment: I think downvoting is harsh but this is undoubtedly a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Development for iPhone on PPC-based computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695558/development-for-iphone-on-ppc-based-computer)

Comment: Up-voting purely because you feel a down-vote is unfair rather than because it's actually a good question.... Are you serious?! Yes we shouldn't be unnecessarily unpleasant to newbies but "I'll +1 to give them some rep"? Rep is earned not gifted, that's the whole point. This really is the beginning of the end.

Answer (score 6):

No, you need Snow Leopard to run the latest SDK.

Comment: +1 Wow, I've been seeing plenty of people double/triple-post lately. Some server latency issue?

Comment: Just got it again:408 Request Time-out
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.

Answer (score 1):

Any intel mac should be able to run Snow Leopard.  The way you worded it, it sounds like you have an "Apple MacBook Pro with Intel".  If so, you can install Snow Leopard and get developing.

http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html

Comment: +1 True. I've got a feeling they don't have an intel mac though.

Comment: No I don't have intel mac which is why I originally ask the question! I'm planning on purchasing an inexpensive Apple computer so that I can develop iPhone apps on it.

Comment: Yea I thought so, so the answer is no, you need an intel mac. Sorry :)

Comment: So would the Macbook Pro work since it has Intel chip installed in it? I can always have somebody install the latest version of Snow Leopard if it's not already installed on the laptop that I buy.

Comment: If you buy an intel Macbook, you should be able to install Snow Leopard if it isn't already on it. Don't forget to purchase the upgrade though, it doesn't cost much!